# Minimal Map implementation with weak values

Tags: java, hash-map, weak-references

What follows is an implementation of the `java.util.Map` interface with *weak values*. This means that entries should be removed from the map when their values become *weakly reachable*, in the same way that `WeakHashMap` removes entries whose *keys* have become *weakly reachable*.

It is intended to fully implement the contract of the `Map` interface while being optimized for simplicity rather than performance. It works correctly under a set of simple test cases, some of which try to provoke race conditions by asynchronously invoking the garbage collector while accessing the map.

Besides whatever I may have missed, I mainly feel uneasy about the these two concerns:

1. I tried to minimize the complexity of this implementation, still, it is rather long, containing 5 classes.
2. My usage of `WeakReference` and whether there are race conditions between e.g. getting or iterating over entries and the garbage collector.

```
import java.lang.ref.Reference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.AbstractSet;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

@SuppressWarnings({ "ConstantConditions", "NullableProblems" })
final class WeakValueMap<K, V> extends AbstractMap<K, V> {
    Map<K, ValueReference<K, V>> backingMap = new HashMap<>();
    ReferenceQueue<V> referenceQueue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
    Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet = new EntrySet();

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(key);

        processQueue();

        return resolveReference(backingMap.get(key));
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(key);
        Objects.requireNonNull(value);

        processQueue();

        return resolveReference(backingMap.put(key, new ValueReference<>(referenceQueue, key, value)));
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(key);

        processQueue();

        return resolveReference(backingMap.remove(key));
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        processQueue();

        return backingMap.size();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ReturnOfCollectionOrArrayField")
    @Override
    public Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        return entrySet;
    }

    private V resolveReference(Reference<V> reference) {
        if (reference == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return reference.get();
        }
    }

    private void processQueue() {
        while (true) {
            ValueReference<?, ?> reference = (ValueReference<?, ?>) referenceQueue.poll();

            if (reference == null) {
                break;
            }

            backingMap.remove(reference.key);
        }
    }

    private final class EntrySet extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K, V>> {
        @Override
        public Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> iterator() {
            Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> iterationSet = new HashSet<>();

            processQueue();

            for (Map.Entry<K, ValueReference<K, V>> i : backingMap.entrySet()) {
                K key = i.getKey();
                V value = i.getValue().get();

                if (value != null) {
                    iterationSet.add(new Entry(key, value));
                }
            }

            Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> setIterator = iterationSet.iterator();

            return new EntryIterator(setIterator);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean remove(Object o) {
            if (o instanceof Map.Entry<?, ?>) {
                Map.Entry<?, ?> entry = (Map.Entry<?, ?>) o;

                return WeakValueMap.this.remove(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean contains(Object o) {
            if (o instanceof Map.Entry<?, ?>) {
                Map.Entry<?, ?> entry = (Map.Entry<?, ?>) o;

                return entry.getValue().equals(get(entry.getKey()));
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return WeakValueMap.this.size();
        }

        final class EntryIterator implements Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> {
            final Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> setIterator;
            Map.Entry<K, V> currentEntry = null;

            EntryIterator(Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> setIterator) {
                this.setIterator = setIterator;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return setIterator.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public Map.Entry<K, V> next() {
                currentEntry = setIterator.next();

                return currentEntry;
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                setIterator.remove();

                EntrySet.this.remove(currentEntry);
            }
        }
    }

    private final class Entry extends SimpleEntry<K, V> {
        Entry(K key, V value) {
            super(key, value);
        }

        @Override
        public V setValue(V value) {
            put(getKey(), value);

            return super.setValue(value);
        }
    }

    private static final class ValueReference<K, V> extends WeakReference<V> {
        final K key;

        ValueReference(ReferenceQueue<V> referenceQueue, K key, V value) {
            super(value, referenceQueue);

            this.key = key;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to ignore this part of the `Map` javadoc:

> All general-purpose map implementation classes should provide two "standard" constructors: ... and a constructor with a single argument of type `Map, which creates a new map with the same key-value mappings as its argument.

But you can claim that it's not a general-purpose map.

---

You inherit `equals` and `hashCode`, which is finebut note that it behaves a bit strangely (two equal maps can cease to be equal after the GC runs).

---

> Concern Nr. 1: I tried to minimize the complexity of this implementation, still, it is rather long, containing 5 classes.

The `Map` interface is a monster and always requires a lot of code. While 5 classes is a lot, they're not big and I can't see anything superfluous.

> Concern Nr. 2: My usage of WeakReference and whether there are race conditions between e.g. getting or iterating over entries and the garbage collector.

Initially, I thought that you've created a problem by calling `processQueue()` in non-mutator methods. It would means that simply iterating and calling `get` may lead to a `ConcurrentModificationException` thrown by the `backingMap`.

However, you're using a separate `iterationSet`, which is decoupled. This means that you never get this exception, which may not be what you want.

With non-mutators processing the queue and without the `iterationSet`, even a trivial loop like this could throw

```
for (Map.Entry e1 : map.entrySet) {
    for (Map.Entry e2 : map.entrySet) {
    }
}
```

Note that your `EntrySet.iterator()` references the values strongly. This makes it easier to use, but it mayn't be what you want. You could avoid it by reading and storing the (dereferenced) value when calling `hasNext()` (in order to prevent the value from disappearing between the calls to `hasNext` and `next`).

---

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Map.Entry<?, ?>) {
        final Map.Entry<?, ?> entry = (Map.Entry<?, ?>) o;
        return entry.getValue().equals(get(entry.getKey()));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will throw whenever `o` is an entry with a null key or value. I don't think that it's what the `Set` interface allows.

---

All in all, it's a nice code and I couldn't find any problems, but don't celebrate as such thing are hard to find.

You're aware of `com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.weakKeys()`, right?

Comment: Thanks for this very thorough answer! I think the comment about `entrySet().contains()` throwing a `NullPointerException` when it shouldn’t, doesn’t the same apply for `null` keys when calling `entrySet().remove()`? See the update at the bottom of the question.

Comment: About `EntryIterator` holding strong references to the values: This was a deliberate decision, to keep the implementation simpler. My assumption is that iterators are short-lived and thus these references should not be a problem. IMHO it is acceptable for an iterator to not throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` when it could, as long as it behaves reasonably (i.e. not throw some other exception or corrupting the collection).

Comment: @Feuermurmel Removing `null` is documented as "@throws NullPointerException if the specified element is null and this set does not permit null elements", but removing `new SimpleEntry(whatever, null)` is not covered by this javadoc. +++ *"strong references"* - when you know about it, it's fine. Add javadoc? +++ The same for `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: I was thinking about `.entrySet().remove(new SimpleEntry(null, ...))` which _I think_ throws an NPE in the original implementation, which I think it shouldn't, according to the contract of `Set` +++ Yes, these things will included in the documentation.